# how to return user attributes in SAML response in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to add the emailaddress which is stored in LDAP as part of the SAML Response. I read a few articles like http://sureshatt.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/getting-user-claims-over-saml-sso-token.html

but could not get it working. I am using wso2 IS 5.0 version. Whenever I add the claim on the sp configuration save it and when I go back to the screen I could not find the claims that I added earlier. Please help.

Regards
Jay

Answer (score 5):

In IS 5.0.0, configurations have been changed. Therefore you need to do some more things to return the attribute.

1. First please go to the user profile of the user and verify whether LDAP attribute is properly displayed there. Then we can sure that claim mappings are fine.
2. In SAML2 SSO SP configuration you need to enable attribute profile. Tick on `Enable Attribute Profile` Also make sure to tick on `Include Attributes in the Response Always`.  Then you do not want to send the consumer index in SAML auth request.
3. Then please go to SP configuration page and configure the attributes (claims) that you want to send to the SP.

It is better, if you can go through [this](http://soasecurity.org/2014/04/30/open-source-saml2-sso-identity-provider/) blog,  It contains all details how you can configure it with IS 5.0.0

Comment: Asela, Thanks for the reply. After going through the blog it was not the configuration that was causing the issue it was the WSO2 Management console that was causing the issue it was not storing the claims you add in the UI to the underlying table. I manually added the entries in SP_CLAIM_MAPPING table that fixed the issue.

Comment: How to return the session expiry time for a user? Is it possible?